# Web scraping to Select drop down list in website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

After button element "ContentPlaceHolder2_btnSearch" is click, element "cbSite_I" returns to blank. I want element "cbSite_I" to have value 
"Cát Lái" after element "ContentPlaceHolder2_btnSearch" is click. Pls kindly help me accordingly. Thanks.

```
Sub Web()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

On Error GoTo Errorcatch
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://eport.saigonnewport.com.vn/Pages/Common/Containers_new"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

IE.document.forms("form2").elements("cbSite_I").Value = "Cát Lái"
IE.document.forms("form2").elements("txtItemNo_I").Value = "MSKU1183832"
IE.document.forms("form2").elements("ContentPlaceHolder2_btnSearch").Click

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

Range("A2").Value = IE.document.getElementById("grdContainer_DXDataRow0").Children(17).textContent

Set IE = Refresh
Set IE = Nothing
IE.Quit

Exit Sub
Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description
Set IE = Nothing
IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Try describing your post by mentioning the visible text of that desired button.

Comment: Thank sir..
Button : Search. 
elements("cbSite_I") : "Container delivery area" Box. 
elements("txtItemNo_I") : "Container (*)" Box

Comment: @SIM : Any update sir?

Comment: Pls kindly help me !!!!